# css of do vertically middle multiple child (two img and one span) elements in a parent div with auto fixing font-size of text in span

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div `#allcomplex` and it has multiple child divs `.complexmem` 
Child elements of `.complexmem` must be in the middle but the css didn't work on them together. 
I always to have one `img` with fixed size , another `img` with fixed size then a div `.autotext` that has a `span` for detail. 
All of them must be set in the middle of div `.complexmem`, text in the `span` element is being resize by JavaScript code automatically. 

What could be my mistake and how can I fix it?

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/9m30bo83/)

CSS CODE:

```
#allcomplex>div{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display:block;
}

.complexmem{
    width: 40vw;
    height:10vw;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;        
}  

.complexmem>a>img{
    width: 7vw;
    height: 7vw;
    background-color: red;      
}

.complexmem>img{
    width: 12vw;
    height: 7vw;      
    background-color: blue;
}

.complexmem>.autotext{
    width: 20vw;
    height: 7vw;    
    display:inline;
    color:white;
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="allcomplex">

    <div class="complexmem">

        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://science-all.com/images/magnifying-glass-clipart/magnifying-glass-clipart-13.jpg">
        </a>

        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/Microchip_PIC24HJ32GP202.jpg/220px-Microchip_PIC24HJ32GP202.jpg">

        <div class="autotext">
        <span>Computer Center Complex of microchip</span>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="complexmem">

        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://science-all.com/images/magnifying-glass-clipart/magnifying-glass-clipart-13.jpg">
        </a>

        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/PIC16CxxxWIN.JPG/220px-PIC16CxxxWIN.JPG">

        <div class="autotext">
        <span>Laptop Center</span>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

js code for resizing text font-size of span fit to parent width:

```
function resizeFont(parElem, ratio) {

    var parW = parElem.width();
    ratio = ratio || 7;

    parElem.find('span').each(function () {

        console.log($(this).width());
        console.log(parW);
        console.log(ratio);

        $(this).css('font-size',
        parW / $(this).width() * ratio + 'px');

    })
}

resizeFont($(".autotext"));
```

Comment: middle, you mean vertically or horizontally?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9ve7v5vv/ like this?

Comment: Thanks Vitorino , but why you answer it in a comment !

Comment: solved your issue?

Comment: Can you please try my answer?

Comment: yes @HarshSanghani , it's resolved , i said thanks to Vitorino , and your css code is not technical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to `Vitorino` comment

```
#allcomplex>div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.complexmem {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.complexmem:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.complexmem>a>img {
  width: 7vw;
  height: 7vw;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.complexmem>img {
  width: 12vw;
  height: 7vw;
  background-color: blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.complexmem>.autotext {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 7vw;
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the css with the following :-

```
#allcomplex>div{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.complexmem{
    width: 40vw;
    height:10vw;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    display: table;
}  
.complexmem>a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.complexmem>a>img{
    width: 7vw;
    height: 7vw;
    background-color: red;      
}

.complexmem>img{
    width: 12vw;
    height: 100%;      
    background-color: blue;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.complexmem>.autotext{
    width: 20vw;
    height: 7vw;    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color:white;
    background-color: green;
}
```

It may help you.